# Select custom topics via Google News RSS

Tags: rss, feed, google-news

I want to incorporate news on my website, but the main topics need to be "books" or "authors" and etc. Basically, I need to select custom topics like these two I mentioned or the name of an author.

But I can't figure out how to do that, since the documentation is really poor (or I can't find it).

What is the query parameter to add that?

I get this for the RSS currently:

```
http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&topic=n&output=rss
```

Answer (score 3):

To fetch and create Google News items from topics that are not the top listed (top headlines, world, business, nation, science and technology, elections, politics, entertainment, sports, health) you'll need to go to the [Custom sections directory](http://news.google.com/news/directory?cf=all&hl=en&sort=users).

There, you search and load the topic you want to feed news from and grab the RSS link that appears at the bottom of the page.

For example, if you wanted to only fetch the Google News for the Literature topic, you will end up with a feed URL like this:

```
http://news.google.com/news/section?pz=1&cf=all&csid=725f40c3dd857970
```

Here is the topic ID you'll need (Literary in this example):

```
csid=725f40c3dd857970
```

Which can be found when you go via the Custom sections directory page.

If you wanted to do this via the [Google News Search JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/news-search/v1/devguide#setRestriction), don't, because you can't rely on it for much longer. It was [shut down on as of 26 May 2011](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/05/spring-cleaning-for-some-of-our-apis.html).

Answer (score 2):

Your url is close. Try this:

```
http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all&q=SEARCH_TERM&output=rss
```

Just replace `SEARCH_TERM` with your query parameter.